# SQL Server 2012 Pivot Dynamic with Values?

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, pivot

I am trying to build a set with *n* columns, each column represents part of a hierarchy, with the top-level parent on the left and descendants on the right. Under each column should list values for that column/hierarchy only. The image shows what I have so far, which is incorrect because (1) NULLS are showing in the gaps and (2) my "sometext" is not displaying.

What is the right way to get the result I need?

Thanks.

Current code:

```
set nocount on
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tst') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tst
create table #tst ( hiercode varchar(10) , sometext varchar(80) )
Insert into #tst
Select '/7/' , 'aaaa' 
Union All
Select '/7/' , '1' 
Union All
Select '/7/' , '2' 
Union All
Select '/7/1/' , 'bbbb' 
Union All
Select '/7/1/' , '3' 
Union All
Select '/7/1/' , '4' 
Union All
Select '/7/1/' , '5' 
Union All
Select '/7/1/1/' , 'cccc' 
Union All
Select '/7/1/1/' , '6' 
Union All
Select '/7/1/1/' , '7' 
Union All
Select '/7/1/1/' , '8' 
Union All
Select '/7/1/2/' , 'dddd' 
Union All
Select '/7/1/3/' , 'eeee' 
Union All
Select '/7/2/' , 'ffff' 
Union All
Select '/7/2/1/' , 'gggg' 
Union All
Select '/7/2/1/' , '9' 
Union All
Select '/7/2/1/' , '10' 
Union All
Select '/7/2/1/' , '11' 
Union All
Select '/7/2/2/' , 'hhhh' 
Union All
Select '/7/2/3/' , 'iiii' 
Union All
Select '/7/2/4/'  , 'jjjj' 
Union All
Select '/7/3/' , 'kkkk'
Union All
Select '/7/3/1/' , 'llll' 
Union All
Select '/7/3/2/'  , 'mmmm' 
Union All
Select '/7/3/3/' , 'nnnn' 
declare @cols as nvarchar(max) = 
    STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.hiercode) 
            FROM #tst c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'') 
select @cols
declare @statemt as nvarchar(max) = 
     'SELECT  ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select hiercode
                    , sometext
                from #tst
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(hiercode)
                for hiercode in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '
select @statemt
execute(@statemt)
```

This is the set that is produced.

[image: Set with NULLs in the wrong places]

This is the set that I want (excuse extraneous quote marks).

[image]

All ideas appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same column in the aggregate portion of the PIVOT as what will be the new column names.

The `max()` aggregate should be selecting the data that you want displayed in the column.

Try using:

```
declare @cols as nvarchar(max) = 
    STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.hiercode) 
            FROM #tst c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'') 

select @cols
declare @statemt as nvarchar(max) = 
     'SELECT  ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select hiercode
                    , sometext
                from #tst
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(sometext)
                for hiercode in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '
select @statemt
execute(@statemt);
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/30190).  The above version will return one row for each `hiercode`, if you want to return multiple rows for each `hiercode`, then you need to create a unique sequence that will be used for the grouping - I would use `row_number()`:

```
declare @cols as nvarchar(max) = 
    STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.hiercode) 
            FROM #tst c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'') 

declare @statemt as nvarchar(max) = 
     'SELECT  ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select hiercode
                    , sometext,
                    row_number() over(partition by hiercode
                                      order by hiercode) seq
                from #tst
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(sometext)
                for hiercode in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '
execute(@statemt);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/30191). This will generate:

```
|    /7/ | /7/1/ | /7/1/1/ | /7/1/2/ | /7/1/3/ |  /7/2/ | /7/2/1/ | /7/2/2/ | /7/2/3/ | /7/2/4/ |  /7/3/ | /7/3/1/ | /7/3/2/ | /7/3/3/ |
|--------|-------|---------|---------|---------|--------|---------|---------|---------|---------|--------|---------|---------|---------|
|   aaaa |  bbbb |    cccc |    dddd |    eeee |   ffff |    gggg |    hhhh |    iiii |    jjjj |   kkkk |    llll |    mmmm |    nnnn |
|      1 |     3 |       6 |  (null) |  (null) | (null) |       9 |  (null) |  (null) |  (null) | (null) |  (null) |  (null) |  (null) |
|      2 |     4 |       7 |  (null) |  (null) | (null) |      10 |  (null) |  (null) |  (null) | (null) |  (null) |  (null) |  (null) |
| (null) |     5 |       8 |  (null) |  (null) | (null) |      11 |  (null) |  (null) |  (null) | (null) |  (null) |  (null) |  (null) |
```

Comment: Amazing. I think I get it. Since I spent an hour+ getting it this far, I can spend another hour understanding the need for the sequence in the pivot. Thanks!

Comment: @Snowy Since a pivot is aggregating data, if you don't have some sort of unique value for each row in the `hiercode`, then the max will only return one row.  By creating that number, you will return each row that you want.  Any columns that are in the subquery will be included when the grouping is done for the aggregate function.  :)